# JavaScript select an css class for jquery.inputmask

Tags: javascript, jquery-inputmask

Hi for my script i must use jquery.inputmask but I have a problem with the input field selection. I can't use ids (because of other script) so I tried this:

```
var FormComponents = function () {

    var handleInputMasks = function () {
        $.extend($.inputmask.defaults, {
            'autounmask': true
        });

        $(":input").inputmask("99999.99999.99999", {placeholder:" ", clearMaskOnLostFocus: true }); //default
    }

    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function () {
            handleInputMasks();
        }

    };

}();
```

All work but now all inputs have the inputmask. But I only want to have the input with the css class `inputmask`.

So I tried

`$(".inputmask input[type=text]").inputmask("99999.99999.99999", {placeholder:" ", clearMaskOnLostFocus: true }); //default`

and

`$(".inputmask :input").inputmask("99999.99999.99999", {placeholder:" ", clearMaskOnLostFocus: true }); //default`

but both are not working. Anybody an idea?

Comment: Why not just `.inputmask` or `input.inputmask`?

Answer (score 0):

Put your class after your element selector:

```
$("input.inputmask").inputmask("99999.99999.99999", {placeholder:" ", clearMaskOnLostFocus: true }); //default
```

or else just use the class with no element:

```
$(".inputmask").inputmask("99999.99999.99999", {placeholder:" ", clearMaskOnLostFocus: true }); //default
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `input` itself has the class, then one of these:

```
$('input.inputmask');
$('.inputmask');
```

should be better.
Using a space in the selector implies a `child`, so for example

```
$('.inputmask input[type="text"]')
```

selects an `input[type="text"]` **inside** `.insputmask`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I must post the code to understand. Because I think I have explain first something a little bit false.

```
<div class="inputmask" style="position: relative;">
<input type="text" class="input-medium" style="padding-right: 24px;">
<span class="editable-clear-x" style="display: block;"></span>
</div>
```

I can't use the `class="input-medium"` because it is an class its used in other input. So I must use inputmask.

Comment: I tried $('.inputmask input[type="text"]') but it doesn't work.